# IIS 7 - URL Rewrite - "is not a file" condition not working

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

In IIS 7 I've created a URL Rewrite rule which checks for URLs which don't end with a /

```
<rule name="AddTrailingSlashRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*[^/])$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

But for some reason this causes a problem with the ScriptResource.axd as the / gets added to the end of the file (ScriptResource.axd/?d=234...), how do I resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScriptResource.axd isn't actually a file.  So I think your only option is to modify the url regex to not match when the url includes ScriptResource.axd (and aren't there others; webresource.axd).

Let us know if you need help with the regex.